# How to create `IconData` from text in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create a icon from a text like currency symbol. Currency symbols are not available in material icons and i don't want to use any third party library. I want to convert the text string like '$' to Icons and use them.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement try below code hope its help to you:

**Using `\` character**

```
      Text(
        '\$ Search',
      ),
```

Your Output Screen like-> [image]

Using Flutter **Unicode character**. You found Unicode character [here](http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/1.0/emoji-data.txt)

```
    Text(
        'Your \u{1F4B2} Symbol',
      ),
```

Your result screen like->[image]

You can add any **Symbol in between text**

```
  Wrap(
      crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text('Your'),
        Icon(Icons.add),
        Text('Icon'),
      ],
    ),
```

Your result screen like-> [image]

Or in **VS Code** you can used `Windows + .` keys and add any symbol on your need

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one. 0024 is Unicode for $

```
Icon( IconData(0x0024, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),size: 50, ))
```

Comment: May I know. Have you tried this?

Comment: Its ok for *$* not for any other text i wanted to add